# Laravel keeps passing GenericUser to Policies instead of my User Model

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, authorization, laravel-8

I am trying to use the standard Laravel `auth` related functionality. I have the standard login, register, logout, etc... working fine. But my problem is that whenever I go to use functions like `Auth::user()` this is returning the `GenericUser` model rather than my own `App/Models/User.php` model. The problem is that my User's model has some foreign key references to other data so I would like to work exclusively with my `User` model.

For example, when trying to make a `Policy` I am running into an error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Policies\ContractPolicy::before() must be an
> instance of App\Models\User, instance of Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser
> given

And the code simply looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Contract;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ContractPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function before(User $user, $ability)
    {
        if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return $user->isMember();
    }
}
```

The `GenericUser` model is indeed returning the data from the `users` table, but the problem is that it is completely different from what my `User` model gives, and thus includes nothing like the foreign key references or functions I added. I was under the impression that I could switch the model used by switching the `config/auth.php` provider. Which I did and nothing seemed to change:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

     'users' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
         'table' => 'users',
     ],
],
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are telling it to use the `GenericUser`, that is what the `database` driver uses and an array can't have duplicate keys

Comment: @lagbox I switched it to use `eloquent` and that seems to make things work. Are there any negative implications of this switch? I can't seem to find much documentation describing how these two different providers work. If you have any reference I can read over that would be great

Comment: one uses Eloquent to do the database query and uses a Model and the other one uses Query Builder to query the database and returns a `GenericUser` to represent the current user  ... you would want to use `eloquent` since you are using a Model (which you can easily customize), but its the same database table in the end

Comment: @lagbox Sounds good, thanks! That helped clear things up for me. Feel free to submit an answer with this. I know it's a simple fix, but it saved me a headache for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the `users` provider to use the 'database' driver:

```
 'users' => [
     'driver' => 'database',
     'table' => 'users',
 ],
```

Adjust that to use the 'eloquent' driver instead:

```
 'users' => [
     'driver' => 'eloquent',
     'model' => App\Models\User::class,
 ],
```

The 'database' driver uses Query Builder to interact with the database table and returns an object of `GenericUser` to represent the currently authenticated user.

The 'eloquent' driver uses an Eloquent Model to interact with the database and returns a Model instance. If you like relationships and all the other features of Eloquent then you should stick with using the 'eloquent' driver. Also, you have defined your Policy methods to be expecting a particular Model passed to its methods.